# Apache requests crashing site

Tags: apache, ip

I know this is a very broad question but I don't really know how else to solve it without starting here.

A site that I am working on keeps crashing and when I spoke to the hosting provider's support team they told me it is because the site is making multiple apache requests to an external connection. He gave me the IP address it is requesting info from but my problem is that the site is massive and has multiple users. How can I find exactly where on the site the request is coming from?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified what O.S. and/or what kind of service used (shared hosting, VPS etc.), anyway, apache logs are normally located in:

Debian based (Ubuntu etc.): `/var/log/apache2/access.log`

Fedora based (RHEL, CentOS etc.): `/var/log/httpd/access_log`

But the name of file can be other if your server is configured with virtualhosts and with custom log directives. Ie.:

```
(...)
ErrorLog path/to/error.log
CustomLog path/to/access.log combined
(...)
```

Check logs with `grep`, `tail` or any other tool.

You can block the suspect IP, by the following .htaccess rules:

```
order allow,deny 
deny from 1.2.3.4 
allow from all
```

Change **1.2.3.4** with the bad IP.

Probably your website already has an .htaccess in their root directory. Ex.: path/to/my_site/.htaccess